# Iterating through array in getJSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to invoke a getJSON function for each value in an array and if the user is offline, display their name. However, I keep getting undefined. When a number is hard coded for i though, it works fine.

```
function getStreamersList() {
    $('#listOfStreams').html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
        console.log("This works: " + streamers[i]);
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + streamers[i], function(data) {
            if (data.stream !== null) {
                $('#onlineStreams').append('<div class="online"><p>' + data.stream.channel.status + '</p></div>');
            } else {
                console.log(streamers[i]);
                $('#offlineStreams').append('<div class="offline"><p>' + streamers[i] + ' is offline.</p></div>');
            }
        }, 'jsonp')
    }   
}
```

Can someone please explain what's happening? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually you are supposed to iterate after getting the AJAX, not before that. This will definitely make the server go mad! `:(` Sends a lot of requests in less time.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Would you mind elaborating? I'm not sure what you mean. Should I pass the data into an array and then do the if/else on the new array?